# Fast EMA calculation on large dataset with irregular time intervals

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have data that has 800,000+ rows. I want to take an Exponential Moving Average (EMA) of one of the columns. The times are not evenly sampled and I want to decay the EMA on each update (row). The code I have is this:

```
window = 5            
for i in range(1, len(series)):
    dt = series['datetime'][i] - series['datetime'][i - 1]
    decay = 1 - numpy.exp(-dt / window)
    result[i] = (1 - decay) * result[i - 1] + decay * series['midpoint'].iloc[i]
return pandas.Series(result, index=series.index)
```

The problem is, for 800,000 rows, this is very slow. Is there anyway to optimize this using some other features of numpy? I can't vectorize it because `results[i]` is dependent on `results[i-1]`.

sample data here:

```
Timestamp             Midpoint
1559655000001096130    2769.125
1559655000001162260    2769.127
1559655000001171688    2769.154
1559655000001408734    2769.138
1559655000001424200    2769.123
1559655000001433128    2769.110
1559655000001541560    2769.125
1559655000001640406    2769.125
1559655000001658436    2769.127
1559655000001755924    2769.129
1559655000001793266    2769.125
1559655000001878688    2769.143
1559655000002061024    2769.125
```

Comment: Why don't you just use the `ewm` function in pandas? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ewm.html

Comment: the `alpha` is not the same across all rows.

Comment: Can you please provide some sample data, e.g. 5-10 rows?

Comment: added to original post

Comment: At the very least you can vectorize calculating `decay`s as a list...

Comment: Is this financial data?  That is, are there natural gaps in the data that should be ignored? For example, one would have a large `dt` value on Monday morning from the preceding Friday.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about something like the following which takes me 0.34 seconds to run on a series of irregularly spaced data with 900k rows?  I am assuming the window of 5 implies a 5 day span.

First, let's create some sample data.

```
# Create sample data for a price stream of 2.6m price observations sampled 1 second apart.
seconds_per_day = 60 * 60 * 24  # 60 seconds / minute * 60 minutes / hour * 24 hours / day
starting_value = 100
annualized_vol = .3
sampling_percentage = .35  # 35%
start_date = '2018-12-01'
end_date = '2018-12-31'

np.random.seed(0)
idx = pd.date_range(start=start_date, end=end_date, freq='s')  # One second intervals.
periodic_vol = annualized_vol * (1/ 252 / seconds_per_day) ** 0.5
daily_returns = np.random.randn(len(idx)) * periodic_vol
cumulative_indexed_return = (1 + daily_returns).cumprod() * starting_value
index_level = pd.Series(cumulative_indexed_return, index=idx)

# Sample 35% of the simulated prices to create a time series of 907k rows with irregular time intervals.
s = index_level.sample(frac=sampling_percentage).sort_index()
```

Now let's create a generator function to store the latest value of the exponentially weighted time series.  This can run c. 4x faster by installing numba, importing it and then adding the single decorator line above the function definition `@jit(nopython=True)`.

```
from numba import jit  # Optional, see below.

@jit(nopython=True)  # Optional, see below.
def ewma(vals, decay_vals):
    result = vals[0]
    yield result
    for val, decay in zip(vals[1:], decay_vals[1:]):
        result = result * (1 - decay) + val * decay
        yield result
```

Now let's run this generator on the irregularly spaced series `s`. For this sample with 900k rows, it takes me 1.2 seconds to run the following code.  I can further cut down the execution time to 0.34 seconds by optionally using the the just in time compiler from [numba](https://numba.pydata.org/).  You first need to [install](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/installing.html) that package, e.g. `conda install numba`. Note that I used a list compehension to populate the `ewma` values from the generator, and then I assign these values back to the original series after first converting it to a dataframe.

```
# Assumes time series data is now named `s`.
window = 5  # Span of 5 days?
dt = pd.Series(s.index).diff().dt.total_seconds().div(seconds_per_day)  # Measured in days.
decay = (1 - (dt / -window).apply(np.exp))
g = ewma_generator(s.values, decay.values)
result = s.to_frame('midpoint').assign(
    ewma=pd.Series([next(g) for _ in range(len(s))], index=s.index))

>>> result.tail()
                       midpoint        ewma
2018-12-30 23:59:45  103.894471  105.546004
2018-12-30 23:59:49  103.914077  105.545929
2018-12-30 23:59:50  103.901910  105.545910
2018-12-30 23:59:53  103.913476  105.545853
2018-12-31 00:00:00  103.910422  105.545720

>>> result.shape
(907200, 2)
```

To make sure the numbers follow our intuition, let's visualize the result taking hourly samples.  This looks good to me.

```
obs_per_day = 24  # 24 hourly observations per day.
step = int(seconds_per_day / obs_per_day)
>>> result.iloc[::step, :].plot()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A slight improvement may be obtained by iterating on the underlying numpy arrays instead of on pandas DataFrames and Series:

```
result = np.ndarray(len(series))
window = 5
serdt = series['datetime'].values
sermp = series['midpoint'].values
for i in range(1, len(series)):
    dt = serdt[i] - serdt[i - 1]
    decay = 1 - numpy.exp(-dt / window)
    result[i] = (1 - decay) * result[i - 1] + decay * sermp[i]
return pandas.Series(result, index=series.index)
```

With your sample data it is about 6 times faster that the original method.

Comment: How would I write the loop in C++ and call it in Python? I know the Boost library can be used but is there a recommended way?